# Trying to verify NIST AES example vectos with crypto/aes in Golang

Tags: go, encryption, aes

As the title says, I'm trying to verify one of the [NIST example vectors](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38a.pdf) for AES 128 ECB with Golang crypto/aes implementation.
For example:
From NIST SP 800-38A Appendix F

> F.1.1 ECB-AES128.Encrypt

> Key 2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c

> Block #1
> Plaintext 6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a

> Input Block 6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a

> Output Block 3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97

> Ciphertext 3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97

My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    key := []byte("2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c")
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    in := []byte("6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a")
    fmt.Println(string(in))

    expected := []byte("3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97")
    fmt.Println(string(expected))
    temp := make([]byte, c.BlockSize())
    out := make([]byte, len(in))

    c.Encrypt(temp, in[:c.BlockSize()])
    for i := 0; i < c.BlockSize(); i++ {
        out[i] = temp[i]
    }
    c.Encrypt(temp, in[c.BlockSize():])
    for i := c.BlockSize(); i < len(out); i++ {
        out[i] = temp[i-16]
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))

    decrypted := make([]byte, len(in))
    c.Decrypt(temp, out[:c.BlockSize()])
    for i := 0; i < c.BlockSize(); i++ {
        decrypted[i] = temp[i]
    }
    c.Decrypt(temp, out[c.BlockSize():])
    for i := c.BlockSize(); i < len(decrypted); i++ {
        decrypted[i] = temp[i-16]
    }
    fmt.Println(string(decrypted))
}
```

and my output is:

```
6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a
3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97
~�i�◄`���∟ՁLl��↔��
6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a
```

however I expect them to be:

```
6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a
3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97
3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97
6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a
```

Comment: You are printing out binary data. Print of hex string: `fmt.Printf("%x",out)`

Comment: It does not work, i get 3360ec85c7925b94340e49a64c6ce3a41df28e0d7e8169c91160a5d7f61cd581 instead of 3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97 thanks for your reply!

Comment: Please read the instructions in the paper: "All strings are presented in
hexadecimal notation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4966953/marc) commented, changing strings to hex using DecodeString of encoding/hex library helped me to get the correct solution.

Using EncodeToString I managed to turn to a correct string representation again.
This is the correct answer, thanks to Marc!

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    key, err := hex.DecodeString("2b7e151628aed2a6abf7158809cf4f3c")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    c, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    in, err := hex.DecodeString("6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(in))

    expected, err := hex.DecodeString("3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(expected))
    out := make([]byte, len(in))
    c.Encrypt(out, in)
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(out))

    decrypted := make([]byte, len(in))
    c.Decrypt(decrypted, out)
    fmt.Println(hex.EncodeToString(decrypted))
}
```

Now the output is:

```
6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a
3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97
3ad77bb40d7a3660a89ecaf32466ef97
6bc1bee22e409f96e93d7e117393172a
```